# Render constraints for SliverList

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, customscrollview

It is possible to set some constraints on where the SliverList stops rendering? For example, if we have a transparent SliverAppBar and SliverList, the sliver list will be visible behind the SliverAppBar, can we somehow set the render constraints to only render below the SliverAppBar? PaintOrigin sort of does this but very poorly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SliverClip` widget from my package [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools) for this.
It by default clips away any overlap (which is what happens when having the appbar above it).